# Issue with hand controls and thumb controls in Aframe 1.0.4. Similar code works fine in Aframe 1.0.0

Tags: controls, aframe

In Aframe 1.0.4 I am having an issue where in the Oculus Quest the hand controls in my app only work if you enter VR, exit VR, and enter VR again. Also the thumb controls do not work. However, the code (with one tiny modification to how hand-controls are written) works fine in Aframe 1.0.0.

Here is the code working fine in Oculus Quest with Aframe 1.0.0
Project Page link: https://glitch.com/~keylime
Live App: https://keylime.glitch.me/

To verify that its working fine you need to put on the Oculus Quest, enter VR, pull the thumbstick towards yourself to launch teleport, and point the thumbstick away from yourself to trigger a click (to verify the click point at the box (with the ray from the raycaster) in front of you, when you initiate a click event (while pointing at the box) the box will change color).

In the second example, the code is almost identical, but when you enter VR initially there is no hand-control working, to get it working you have to exit VR and enter VR again, when you do the hand-controls are working, which means you can pull the trigger on the Oculus Touch controller and it will change the color of the cube if you are pointing at the cube (with your ray) however at this point the thumb-controls are not working, so you will notice that if you pull the thumbstick toward you, or push it away from you, nothing happens.

Here is the code not working well in Oculus Quest with Aframe 1.0.4
Project Page link: https://glitch.com/~keynine
Live App: https://keynine.glitch.me

Answer (score 0):

There are redundant controls: laser-controls, hand-contols, mylasercontrols, daydream controls. Keep it simple with just two entities, one per hand. Also hand-controls API is:

`<a-entity hand-controls=“hand: left”></a-entity>`

See [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/hand-controls.html#sidebar)

Comment: I've scoured the docs multiple times, and tried removing all variations of redundant code, but I'm having the same two issues where the "thumb-controls" do not work and the hand-controls only work if I enter vr, exit vr, and enter vr again.
https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/thumb-controls/

Here is another variant of my code: Project page: https://glitch.com/~flownine

My code, that works in Aframe 1.0.0 lets me use thumb-controls which splits the trackpad/thumbstick into 4 buttons. This is for 3dof controllers Nreal, Oculus Go, and 6dof Magic Leap trackpad.